# Wrapping a scrollview in a tablelayout in XML

Tags: android, xml

So, I create table view in XML to which the rows are added dynamically using the following java code:

```
private void fillTable(TableLayout tableLayout, String[] items) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        
        TextView itemText = new TextView(FillingActivity.this);
        itemText.setText(items[i]);
        TableRow row = new TableRow(FillingActivity.this);
        row.addView(itemText);
        if(i % 2 == 1)
            row.setBackgroundColor(color.LightGreen);
        
        tableLayout.addView(row);
        
    }
}
```

The code for a single tablelayout is the following:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/dinnertableviewing"
    android:layout_width="346dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="2dp"
    android:layout_y="210dp" >

</TableLayout>
```

But then when add many items to that table it overlaps with the space for the next tables
here is a picture that shows it:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use AbsoluteLayout. The difficulties you're running into when an AbsoluteLayout contains content that can resize or when you run on differently sized screens (e.g. just about every Android device in the wild) are exactly why AbsoluteLayout is deprecated.

If you're trying to position elements vertically down the screen as they fit, use a LinearLayout with `android:orientation="vertical"`.